# How can I print JPG file using printer Web C#

Tags: c#

How can I print JPG file using printer Web C#

Answer (score 2):

Let me have a guess at what you mean ... :0)

If you want a web client to print the jpg, you must use javascript. Something like this in the html :

```
<a href="JavaScript:window.print();">Print this jpg</a>
```

Set up the css so that only the jpg on the page gets printed.

If you want the server to do it, then you need something like :

```
    {
        PrintDocument doc = new PrintDocument ();
        doc.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler ( doc_PrintPage );
        doc.Print ();
    }

    void doc_PrintPage ( object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e )
    {
        Graphics g = e.Graphics;
        g.DrawImage ( youImage, 0, 0 );
    }
```